# Can Amazon Connect be integrated with a backend service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I have been working on developing a chat-bot for an application. I want to use Amazon Connect to power chat-bot. I wanted to understand, if there is a way through which Amazon Connect fetches response from my backend service whenever client posts a question in chatbox.

Expected flow

```
client (asks question) ---> AWS Connect (calls service) ---> My backend Service (sends response for the question)
```

Thanks

Comment: To build a chatbot in AWS - have you looked at Amazon LEX?

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep logic of generating answer inside my service. Hence, not planning to use LEX.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate the contact flow with a lambda function, then use the lambda function to call your own backend service.